# Can I use `setcs` to set a configspec to a variable?

Tags: bash, clearcase, config-spec

## Background

In clearcase, the command [`setcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm) is used in the following examples:

> **Change the config spec of the current view to the contents of file cspec_REL3.**
>
> cmd-context  setcs cspec_REL3
>
> **Change the config spec of the view whose view tag is jackson_vu to the default config spec.**
>
> cmd-context  setcs –tag jackson_vu –default
>
> **Have the view_server of the current view reread its config spec.**
>
> cmd-context  setcs –current

## Problem

I have a script where I am attempting to do the following:

1. Grab the configSpec of a certain view that I generated earlier in the script (with the [first line edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339941/8981474)).
2. Remove the line in the configspec that says "element * CHECKEDOUT" (I used [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311758/remove-specific-word-in-variable))
3. Set that view's configSpec to the new edits I made.

Below is the code I wrote to attempt this:

```
configSpec=`cleartool catcs -tag $VIEW_NAME | tail -n +2`
noCheckout=`printf '%s\n' "{$configSpec//element * CHECKEDOUT/}"`
cleartool setcs -tag $VIEW_NAME $noCheckout
```

It returns the given error:

```
cleartool: Error: Extra arguments: "SET:"
```

which just so happens to be the first word in the `noCheckout` variable.

## Question

How can I edit and update the configspec using a string variable as an intermediary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, instead of using a string variable as an intermediary, to use a *file*, since `cleartool setcs pname` is:

> `pname`
>    Specifies a text *file* whose contents are to become the view's new config spec.

So, if you can, [redirect the content of your variable to a file (`fprintf`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707098/6309), and use that per-determined filename as argument of your `setcs` command.